# Safari generates "Can't find variable" error although it is already defined in another Javascript page

Tags: javascript, safari

The JavaScript script works with Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari. The code is:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $(window).load(function() {
        myVariable.start();
     });
```

This generates:

```
  ReferenceError: can't find variable: myVariable
```

The variable is defined in another JavaScript page that is included in this page, but for some reason Safari doesn't see the definition in the other page. Is Safari executing this script without loading the page that the variable is defined in?

How can I fix this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Impossible to tell with so little context, but there is no inherent scoping difference between Safari and other browsers with regard to external scripts. `myVaraible` looks like a spelling problem though.

Comment: Please show the exact code. How are you embedding the other JavaScript file?

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid setting global variables.
Maybe try assigning your variable to the window object, on top of the page:

```
window.myVariable = { start: function() {} };
```

Then when you need it:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    window.myVariable.start();
 });
```